# sxhkd - chaining chords doesn't work in autostart.sh of dwm

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, arch-linux, dwm

[`sxhkd`](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd) has a feature where I can chain chords. From `man sxhkd`:

```
When multiple chords are separated by semicolons, the hotkey is a chord
chain: the command will only be executed after receiving each chord of
the chain in consecutive order.
```

Now I want to create a shortcut like "super + o ; t" to open the terminal. That is, I would press the `super` and `o` keys, release them and then press the `t` key. In their GitHub repository, they have an example of chaning chord like this:

```
super + o ; {e,w,m}
        {gvim,firefox,thunderbird}
```

So for my example, it should look like this:

```
super + o ; t
        st
```

Now I save this in a file in `$HOME/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc` and when I run this program in the terminal itself with this command:

```
sxhkd &
```

It prints these warnings:

```
Could not grab key 232 with modfield 0: the combination is already grabbed.
Could not grab key 232 with modfield 16: the combination is already grabbed.
Could not grab key 232 with modfield 2: the combination is already grabbed.
Could not grab key 232 with modfield 18: the combination is already grabbed.
Could not grab key 233 with modfield 0: the combination is already grabbed.
Could not grab key 233 with modfield 16: the combination is already grabbed.
Could not grab key 233 with modfield 2: the combination is already grabbed.
Could not grab key 233 with modfield 18: the combination is already grabbed.
```

And everytime I press the said shortcut, it prints these lines. But it works and it opens my terminal, [st](https://st.suckless.org).

Now the problem is when I want [dwm](https://dwm.suckless.org) to do the same. So I have an `$HOME/.dwm/autostart.sh` script that runs everytime I start dwm. And I put `sxhkd &` in that file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Hotkeys
sxhkd &

# set wallpaper
./set_wallpaper.sh
```

This autostart script is run from this function in `dwm.c`:

```
void
runAutostart(void) {
        system("cd ~/.dwm; ./autostart_blocking.sh");
        system("cd ~/.dwm; ./autostart.sh &");
}
```

But it doesn't work. And I've made sure to restart X after I've made changes to these files. I even rebooted.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same errors. `the combination is already grabbed` i think means you have used that key combination already. Try change it e.g. to `super + alt + o ; t`.